# Splitting with multiple delimiters

Tags: python

i have a line coming in that looks like the following

```
h ="ENGL 1301, preprofessional,,"
```

i want to split them but im not sure how to split with 2 delimiters. ive always only done one this is what i tried

```
for line in h :
    course, catagory = h.strip().split("," , ",,")
    print course, catagory
```

that didnt work so im wondering on how to do this. i see people using regular expressions but the formatting of it throws me off.Help please

Comment: `re.split` would be a good choice.  If your data is actually csv then parse it with `csv` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `re.split` here:

```
>>> from re import split
>>> mystr = "word,word,,word,word"
>>> split(",+", mystr)
['word', 'word', 'word', 'word']
```

`,+` means "one or more commas".

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

To do that, you can split on non-word characters, specified by `\W`:

```
>>> from re import split
>>> mystr = "word,word,;word;word"
>>> split("\W+", mystr)
['word', 'word', 'word', 'word']
>>>
```

Comment: ok what if i have one seperated by a comma, then a semicolon? then how would i do that?

Comment: @ZachSantiago - Simple.  Split on non-word characters.  See my edit.